# Deploying a Jersey webapp on Jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss, migration, jersey, jboss7.x

Currently running some webapps on Jboss AS 4/5 and I am testing migration to jboss7. When I try to deploy a jersey based webapp on JBoss AS 7 (full profile with standalone-preview config file), I get:

```
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.
```

I've done a bit of hunting around on it and found that RestEasy is the default JAX-RS implementation embedded into Application Server. Posts like http://community.jboss.org/message/579996 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8830) mention that the RestEasy deployer takes over.

In AS 6, it seems easier to remove the deployer whereas I have not seen any solutions for AS 7.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

it has already been mentioned in this post : https://community.jboss.org/message/744530#744530 , you can just ask the resteasy module to not scan for other JAX RS implementations in  your webapp; just add this to your web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

worked fine for me

Comment: Worked for me as well! A bit sad the web.xml contains now some specific JBoss configuration. I preferred to get it working by modifying the jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but that didn't work out.

Comment: it sounds like a bug of jboss.. i also wouldnt like to modify my web.xml but seems that there is no other option

Comment: Yes, it works, but maybe you are including additional and non needed artifacts in your deployable war. After adding the <scope>compile</scope> in the jersey-client and jersey-container-servlet dependencies, the error is corrected and without the extra kbytes in the resulting war.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin Yes, but that only works if you don't use Jersey specific features, because you end up using RESTEasy that comes with JBoss if you do that.

Answer (score 6):

Besides removing the entire jaxrs subsystem in `standalone.xml` as mentioned in the other posts excluding the RESTEasy modules in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` may also work.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.async-http-servlet-30" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also check out

- [JBoss Deployment Structure File](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile)
- [Implicit module dependencies for deployments](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct approach is to use app server agnostic JAX-RS application deployment. No need to mess with any JBoss configuration. All you need is, extend [javax.ws.rs.core.Application](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) in your JAX-RS web application. You can find an example [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e188). Then, you need to put this in your web.xml.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>jersey.MyApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Package scanning mechanism does not work correctly on JBoss 7.x. I have tested this approach successfully in JBoss 7.0.2.Final and JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
   </deployment>
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Will do the trick, works great with 7.3AS.ctomc just missed a tiny slash in the end to terminate the  section.:-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run Jersey WS on my JBOSS AS7.

What i do for JBOSS is just remove everything related to jax-rs in standalone.xml

My jersey sample code got from:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

The only thing i do for the jersey is remove the init-param from web.xml and copy jersey lib to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

```
  <!--<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>sample.hello.resources</param-value>
  </init-param>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In web.xml file add the files

        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>

 and comment out the init-param
        <!-- <init-param>
                  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                  <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param> -->

This worked out for me in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final and i did not do any changes in standalone.xml.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahother option:

1. Edit standalone/configuration/standalone.xml and comments out all jaxrs entries. This will configure Jersey instead of RESTEasy.
2. Remove jboss-web.xml from WEB-INF/web.xml. This file no longers works with JBoss 7
3. Edit web.xml, add an init-param com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages configured to your resource's package, like:

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>org.foo</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Deploying-Atmosphere-Jersey-in-JBoss-7.1.x

Answer (score 0):

You can get past this in the standalone configuration by modifying configuration/standalone.xml and removing references to jaxrs in the extensions and profile section. Note, even though I commented those portions out in my standalone.xml, JBoss will automagically remove those references altogether on next startup...

Comment: If you mean that your edits didn't persist, you need to shut the server down before making XML edits. Any changes made to the runtime will be overwritten at reboot. Changes made offline, or via the Management Console or CLI, will be persistent. This way, you can create and load custom server profiles as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me for JBoss 7.1.1 and Jersey 1.17.1. No need to modify `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml`. Besides filtering restEasy in web.xml instruct Jersey to use Jackson. You can read about this configuration [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/json.html).

To save time in configuration guesses, I am posting `web.xml` and `pom.xml` from test project.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestJerseyonJBoss</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.test.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestJerseyOnJBoss</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestJerseyOnJBoss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
           <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
               <groupId>asm</groupId>
               <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.1</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude jaxrs subsystem from being activated for your deployment
add this into META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
     <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  <deployment>
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

or you can go to standalone.xml and remove subsystem there.
To do so, you need to remove

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0">
...
...
<subsystem>
```

part of configuration, extension part of on top can stay it wont hurt either way.
or you can connect to server with CLI and run

```
/subsystem=webservices:remove()
```

Just a note, exclude-subsystems functionality and deployment-strucure:1.2 was added in 7.1.2 and as such will not work on on 7.1.1.