# Error during deploying REST Webservice on JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy a war  (Rest based Webservice)file on a jboss eap 6.3 server . The deployment is failing with the following trace.

I looked into all the dependencies, everything looks fine.

Am i missing something ?

```
        11:22:57,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "RestService.war" (runtime-name: "RestService.war")
    11:22:58,074 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,074 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,075 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,076 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,076 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,076 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,076 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,077 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
    11:22:58,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,079 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,079 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,083 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,084 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,086 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,088 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
    11:22:58,090 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeFromStringEnum' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,091 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeValueOf' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,092 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeFromString' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,094 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$StringConstructor' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,096 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$DateProvider' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,097 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.JAXBStringReaderProviders$RootElementProvider' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
    11:22:58,134 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RestService.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 

jboss.deployment.unit."RestService.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process ph
ase POST_MODULE of deployment "RestService.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api
.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:206)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 5 more

11:22:58,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 5) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "RestService.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RestService.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RestService.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"RestService.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey
.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig"}}
11:22:58,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment RestService.war (runtime-name: RestService.war) in 12ms
11:22:58,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 5) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."RestService.war".POST_MODULE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We see this error because the default jaxrs implementation of jboss is 'Resteasy'.
http://www.jboss.org/resteasy.
Whereas you are using the 'jersey' implementation.
You need to specifically ask the resteasy deployer in your jboss to not scan resteasy implementations. How to do it is mentioned in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953516/deploying-a-jersey-webapp-on-jboss-as-7).

Answer (score 2):

The warnings are erroneous due to JBoss bug [JBEAP-69](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-69). If the class name contains a $ character, you can safely ignore the warning.