# deploying a Jersey JAX-RS WAR to JBoss: ResourceConfig is not proxyable

Tags: jboss, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey-based web application (basically just REST services, no presentation) which I wish to deploy to a JBoss EAP 6.2 server. I first run into the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6953516/274677), which I was able to solve using the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185880/274677) of the question. However, I then run into the following exception thrown by JBoss upon deploying my WAR:

> 16:24:10,142 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."search-rest.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."search-rest.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001437 Normal scoped bean class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method public final org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.setClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader) - Managed Bean [class mjb44.searchapp.rest.Application] with qualifiers [@Default @Any].
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableClassException(Proxies.java:229)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:180)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypesExceptionInt(Proxies.java:195)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypesException(Proxies.java:169)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:148)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:383)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:368)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>       ... 3 more
>
> 16:24:10,350 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "search-rest.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
>   {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"search-rest.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"search-rest.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
>       Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001437 Normal scoped bean class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method public final org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.setClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader) - Managed Bean [class mjb44.searchapp.rest.Application] with qualifiers [@Default @Any]."}}

My Application is defined simply as:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application () {
        register(mjb44.searchapp.filters.CORSFilter.class);
    }
}
```

… and so it is neither final nor contains any final methods. As such the problem obviously has to do with `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` which however I cannot control. I also opened a discussion in JBoss forums [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/966891#966891).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the only reply I've received so far from the JBoss forums has been that:

> I'm afraid the only JAX-RS implementation supported on EAP is RESTEasy.

… which seems weird as I guess if I provide the JAX-RS implementation in the WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` then any web container should be fine with that.